# iterate the loop in same div in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

[image]

HTML page:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClientClick="return ShowModalyardPopup(this)" ToolTip="YardNotification">
    <div class="rectangle13" onclick="Getrectangle2()" >
        <asp:Label ID="lblyard5_1boxcargoname" runat="server" ></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="lblyard5_1boxcargostock" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnidrec2" runat="server" />
    </div>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

.cs Page

```
dtAssetModelDetails = YardBLL.GetLastYard5Data();
lblyard5_1boxcargoname.Text = dtAssetModelDetails.Rows[0]["MATERIAL_NAME"].ToString();
lblyard5_1boxcargostock.Text = dtAssetModelDetails.Rows[0]["CAPACITY"].ToString();
```

This is my code for `html` and `aspx.cs` page.

I want to iterate over all values in the `div`.

Below given image is for `div`, I need to display diffrent values with one `div`.
Please suggest me how to use loop here.

[image]

Comment: above given is static rectangles which is used in div but i want same as dynamic..please suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are filling the data table properly with the function you have. It looks wrong to me. Debug and see if you are getting values in the foreach loop correctly and then go on with the solution.

You'll need to give me a clear picture to solve this question. Anyway, I'm making small amendments for you to continue and play with.

```
string lblOne = "lblOne";
string lblTwo = "lblTwo";

int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow item in dtAssetModelDetails.Rows)
{
    //Assuming divyrd1 is the Parent div
    HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    div.Attributes.Add("id", divId);
    divyrd1.Controls.Add(div);

    Label l1 = new Label();
    l1.ID = lblOne + divId;
    yrd1.Controls.Add(l1);

    Label l2 = new Label();
    l2.ID = lblTwo + divId;
    yrd1.Controls.Add(l2);

    l1.Text = item["MATERIAL_NAME"].ToString();
    l2.Text = item["CAPACITY"].ToString();

    i++;
    hdnrec3.Value = item["RID"].ToString();
}
```

i used this:

```
 public void GetLastYard1DataBox2()
        {
            DataTable dtAssetModelDetails = null;
            string sData = string.Empty;
            try
            {



                dtAssetModelDetails = YardBLL.GetLastYard1DataBox2();

     string lblOne = "lblOne";
                    string lblTwo = "lblTwo";
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (DataRow item in dtAssetModelDetails.Rows)
                    {
                        string divId = i.ToString();
                        //Assuming divyrd1 is the Parent div
                        HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
                        div.Attributes.Add("id", divId);
                        divyrd1.Controls.Add(div);

                        Label l1 = new Label();
                        l1.ID = lblOne + divId;
                        yrd1.Controls.Add(l1);

                        Label l2 = new Label();
                        l2.ID = lblTwo + divId;
                        yrd1.Controls.Add(l2);

                        l1.Text = item["MATERIAL_NAME"].ToString();
                        l2.Text = item["CAPACITY"].ToString();

                        i++;
                        hdnrec3.Value = item["RID"].ToString();
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception objEx)
                {
                    ErrorLogDAL objErrorLogManager = new ErrorLogDAL();
                    objErrorLogManager.AddErrorLog(objEx);
                    objErrorLogManager = null;

                }
                finally
                {
                    if (((dtAssetModelDetails != null)))
                        dtAssetModelDetails.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzgHm.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rydV.png

Comment: actually its 2 rows   but displaying only one row in  rectangle,but i want single row in single rectangle

Comment: for ex if there are 2 rows then it has to display two rectangle boxes which is used in  div dynamically with values

Comment: @prudhvini I've updated my post to meet your needs. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: @prudhvini **Did you create the parent div in the aspx page?**

it should look like this -> `<div id="divParent" runat="server"></div>`

Comment: can u plz explaine me what is id and l1 in  l1.Id = lblOne+divId;

Comment: @prudhvini So with the above-mentioned line you are adding the id attribute for the dynamic labels we are creating for every data row. We are doing it so that we could assign the values for the label from the code behind (we are doing it after its creation in the foreach loop)

Comment: (lblOne+i.ToString()).Text = row["MATERIAL_NAME"].ToString();
    (lblTwo+i.ToString()).Text = row["CAPACITY"].ToString();   it showing error in .Text plz suggest me y it will be

Comment: @prudhvini Pls attach the errors you are receiving as well. It's not possible to fix if you don't know what the error is.

Comment: Error 52 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: sir its working and fetching values properly, but actually it fetching two rows from database and displaying in colour rectangle but i want one record in one rectangle so for that it has to display two diffrent rectangles for indivisual  set of records or values

Comment: sir its working and fetching values properly, but actually it fetching two rows from database and displaying in single rectangle like abaove image but i want one record in one rectangle so for that it has to display two diffrent rectangles for indivisual  set of records or values.i want like my first image as pink and green

Comment: @prudhvini With the foreach loop you will be creating two div's as there are two rows in the data table. 

How are you adding the styles for the newly created dynamic classes? I believe that is the issue somehow. But you'll hv to giv me more info on it to figure out ur current problem.

Comment: @prudhvini I understand what you are getting. In order to fix you need to answer my question - How are you adding the styles for the newly created dynamic classes?

Comment: Sorry to late inform. this is working now properly.. thank you soo much for your spontaneous replay.....

Comment: @prudhvini Always happy to help a fellow developer. Don't forget to upvote or make the answer as correct if it helped you in any way. Cheers :)